# Proposed definition of a countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following proposed definition:

A set $X$ is *countable* iff $X=\emptyset$ or there exists $x_0\in X$ and $f:X\to X$ such that:

> $\forall P\subset X: [x_0\in P  \land \forall x\in P: [f(x) \in P] \implies P=X]$

In other words, a set $X$ is countable iff $X$ is empty or induction holds on $X$.

Note that, by this definition, if $X=\{x_0\}$ then $X$ is countable. The identity function on $X$ would be the required "successor function."

By this definition, the set of natural numbers is trivially countable.

Comments? Is this definition anything new?

Comment: I think it's not that hard to show that every countable set satisfy this property, but can you prove the converse? If not, do you know about any counterexamples?

Comment: @yanko: Set $P=\{f^n(x_0)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ to get an explicit surjection $\mathbb N\to X$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh right, simple! Thanks.

Comment: I think a cleaner definition would be to drop the $X=\emptyset$ part and use a universal quantifier on $x_0$. In other words: "$X$ is countable if, for all $x_0\in X$, there exists $f:X\to X$ such that ...". This avoids "$X=\emptyset$ or there exists $x_0\in X$ ...". I believe these two definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

We can show that if $X$ satisfies this property, then there is a surjection $g:\mathbb N\rightarrow X$. Thus $X$ is countable in the usual sense. Of course the converse holds, as you already know.

Define $g$ as $g(0)=x_0$ and $g(n+1)=f(g(n)),\forall n\in\mathbb N$. Then by the property in question, the image of $g$ is equal to $X$, so $g$ is surjective.

---

Hope this helps.